# C# WPF TreeViewItem align Content

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, alignment

I have a problem with the WPF element "TreeViewItem".
Namely, I want to place the content (text) in the middle, but unfortunately I can't get this.
Here is my problem:
[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlXRh.png)

And here my code:

```
var treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem
            {
                Header = name,
                IsSelected = false,
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 200, 0),
                HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            };
```

I hope you can help me, thanks for the answers :)

Comment: can you please delete `Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 200, 0)` and try again?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Sure, but then the border is exactly the same size as the letter and I want the border to be the same size as the picture.

Comment: Ahh then, instead of padding maybe you can try to give width property? so it will size as you want and content will be at the center i believe. That's all i can find ^^

Comment: This didnt help. The solution was to set padding "200,0,200,0".

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was that I also had to set Padding to 200 at the beginning, so:

```
 var treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem
            {
                Header = name,
                IsSelected = false,
                Padding = new Thickness(200, 0, 200, 0),
                HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            };
```

Comment: Using Padding to force the TreeViewItem to stretch is a bad solution. It will eliminate the resize behavior to adopt to the parent's size. If you make the TreeView bigger or smaller, you would have to adjust the Padding. You should always avoid using Margin or Padding to position elements. This properties were not designed for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to override the `TreeViewItem` template to modify the content layout. The item's content is arranged using a `Grid`. You simply have to make the `Border`, that contains the item header's `ContentPresenter`, span the last two columns. This allows the `TreeViewItem` to stretch to occupy the available space.
As the final step, the `TreeView.HorizontalContentAlignment` must be set to `Center`.

Using a solution that relies on absolute positioning like applying a `Padding` or `Margin` is not optimal. Such a solution makes the whole layout static. The `TreeView` will no longer resize properly.

**TreeViewItem Style**

```xml
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                              Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                          Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                          Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
          <Border x:Name="Bd"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>
          <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                    Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                          Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Width"
                          Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="75" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                          Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Height"
                          Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="19" />
          </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```